# How to generate GraphSON data for export with Remote Traversal?

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server, graphson

Example Code(JAVA):

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.open(yml.getFile());
DriverRemoteConnection driver = DriverRemoteConnection.using(cluster, "graph_traversal");
GraphTraversalSource allGraph = AnonymousTraversalSource.traversal().withRemote(driver);

// Using Io --> generate a file in server-side
allGraph.Io("File.json").write().iterate()

// Using GraphSONWriter 
GraphSONMapper mapper = GraphSONMapper.build().addRegistry(JanusGraphIoRegistry.instance()).version(GraphSONVersion.V3_0).create();
GraphSONWriter writer = GraphSONWriter.build().mapper(mapper).create();
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

// output --> "" (Empty)
writer.writeGraph(output, allGraph.getGraph());

// output --> "~" (Only Vertex Ids)
writer.writeVertices(output, allGraph.V());
```

I'm trying to export a Graph as GraphSON with remote server. But IO step doesn't provide a functionality for remote-export.
With GraphSonWriter, It doesn't write the contents properly.
How can I export a graph in GraphSON format with remote-server environment?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until TinkerPop provides better support around the `g.io()` step for remote environments, it still only works well for reading and writing local to where the Gremlin execution occurs. If you want to export a graph to GraphSON at a remote source then there are a few options depending on the graph you are using. You tagged this question with JanusGraph so I'll focus on that. You could:

1. Send a script than instantiates a `GraphSONWriter` on the server and then provide `writeGraph()` an `OutputStream` that will write to a `byte[]` or `String` and then return that to your client.
2. I assume this is a "small" graph that will likely fit in memory so just do `g.E().subgraph('sg').cap('sg')` and copy the whole graph to a subgraph. That will yield you a `TinkerGraph` on the client and from there you can use `io()` as you like to write the graph locally to GraphSON. This only works if you are using Java as other languages don't yet support `subgraph()` well.
3. Forgo use of Gremlin Server and create a local `JanusGraph` instance and then `io()` will work as normal.

Comment: Thank you :) It is helpful.